# Undefined control sequence with \hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, undefined

I get `Undefined control sequence` error when I use `\hyperref` to refer to the desired section.
I want to make the section number refer to the section when I click on it at the same time i want the number of the section appears automaticly by \ref . Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}

\renewcommand{\harvardurl}{URL:\url}
\graphicspath{./301/Alaa Ali Yousef/}

\title {Example \LaTeX \quad     article for course 4ME301}
\author{Alaa Ali Yousef  \\ 9105195789 \\ay222ej@lnu.se\\   Linnaeus University, Växjö }


\begin{document}
    \maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    This assignment aims to make you familiar with the basic features
    of \LaTeX which should come useful when preparing your own reports,
    and eventually your master thesis. You should try to replicate “as
    close as possible” this PDF document using \LaTeX. This does not
    exclude making some changes as long as they are relevant. Submission
    instructions can be found in Section \ref{secondSection}.
    \end{abstract}

\section{Introduction section}
\label{firstsection}
There is a handy book about \LaTeX {\color{green}\cite{lamport1994latex}} available at the LNU library, but if
you search online you should find many examples and guides, like e.g. {\color{green}\cite{WEBSITE:2}}
on {\color{green}\cite{WEBSITE:3}}, or extensive information on {\color{green}\cite{WEBSITE:1}}.


\section{How to submit} 

\label{secondSection}
\
When you compose and compile the final version of this document, you should upload a .zip file on the course moodle that contains:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item the compiled .pdf file;  
    \item   the source files (.tex, .bib, and the image file).
\end{enumerate}
The filename template for these files, besides the image file, should be:

\begin{itemize}
    \item 4ME301-LaTeX-[yoursurname].xxx 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

How can i use \ref and \hyperref or \hyperlink to make the number of the section clickable and which are more suitable to use \hyperref or \hyperlink?

I used both of them and get the same error

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site plase provide a full but minimal example showing what you are doing. My guess you haven't loaded the `hyperref` package. But since you give not example document we cannot know for sure.

Comment: You say that you "use `\hyperref` to refer to the desired section", yet your code snippet shows a `\ref` instruction. Please clarify.

Comment: With `hyperref` loaded, the input `Section \ref{secondSection}` already makes the section number `2` clickable. But you also need to have a following page, so that the pdf reader can have the space to actually skip to the section 2 when you click that `2`.

Comment: Which `LaTeX` engine you used, from your `MWE` you should use either `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` to produce the output...

Comment: unrelated but `of \LaTeX which` should be `of \LaTeX\ which`

Comment: If I run your example there is no error and the **2** at the end of the abstract is a hyperlink that takes you to section 2. What is your question?